# How use inner join in hibernate hql fastest

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I've got 3 entities: Question, Test and Category. Question has link to his test and category has links to her tests, I'm not very good in hql queries, I tried several and they arn't working: `"select q from Question q where q.test in (select c.tests from Category c where c.id=:categoryId)"` with the following error: "could not extract ResultSet".

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(
                "select q from Question q where q.test in (select c.tests from Category c where c.id=:categoryId)");
query.setParameter("categoryId", category.getId());
return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 0):

You are using EntityManager, so by calling `createQuery` you are actually using Java Persistence Query and not HQL.

To use HQL, you need to obtain Hibernate Session, for that you can use:

```
((Session)getEntityManager().getDelegate()).createQuery("yourquery")
```

See if that solves the problem, I've read JQL has some issues with `IN` clauses.

Comment: I'm thinking it isn't good use HQL if in all other places in project is using JPQ, it there query that can do it in JPQ?

Comment: Would this query do?
`select q from Question q
join q.test t
where t.category.categoryId = :categoryId`

Comment: well can't you make that relation bidirectional? sometimes it really helps easing things up

Comment: otherwise, please post your full stacktrace and your object mappings

Comment: Project is nearly finished, and this query is using only for not show all questions on one page, if make relation bideractional it take much changes.

Comment: then please post more code so we can help you; my guess is that the query should work and the problem is elsewhere

Comment: "select q from Question q join q.test t where t.category.categoryId = :categoryId", this query cann't work because test hasn't got any links to his category.

Comment: I understand, but can you please post your whole stacktrace and your mappings for the three entities involved

Comment: I found a decideon, I'm sure it isn't very fast, but it is using only in admin module, so maybe then it will be changed:        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select q from Question q where q.test in :tests");
        query.setParameter("tests", category.getTests());

Answer (score 0):

if relation is One to Many, otherwise use elements() function to test occurrences.

```
String hql ="select q form Question q " +
            "join q.category category " + 
            "where category.id = :id ";

return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql)
        .setLong("id", categoryId)
        .list();
```

Comment: Question hasn't got link to category.

Comment: In this case post your code (entity model), your posted question is not quite clear.